# NumberFormat through Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I got to search and find similar issues on this, but not specifically on this

```
'Why this works:
Range("A2").NumberFormat = "[>999999]0,,\M;[>999]0,K;0"

'And not this:
Range("A2").NumberFormat = "[>999999999]0,,,B;[>999999]0,,\M;0"
```

What I am trying to accomplish is to have billions as "B" and millions as "M" (ideally all three with thousands as "K").
As always thanks for the help/explanations.

Comment: You're missing a backslash before the B in the format code.

Comment: Try: `[>=1000000000]#.##00,,," B";[>=1000000]#0.0,," M";#0.0," K"`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, thanks for the quick replies, I got it to work.
Backslashes are mandatory not just for reserve "M" letter

```
Range("A2").NumberFormat = "[>=1000000000]0,,,\B;[>=1000000]0,,\M;0,\K"
```

Thanks Rory